# Ubuntu 14.04 failed to install VMware - Player 2.5.5

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-player

I tried to install VMware player on my host. After the installation completed, I executed the binary and it popped the following dialog.

[image]

The one I chose did not work.

[image]

I then tried to enter the following command:

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

But this still did not work.

```
gcc and kernel headers must be installed
```

I have done the soft link to the kernel version but this does not help.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

Please advice.

Comment: What version of VMPlayer are you trying to load?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/generated/utsrelease.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/
sudo ln -s /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/generated/autoconf.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/
sudo ln -s /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/generated/version.h /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/
```

Now the path of kernel headers should be `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include`

Comment: Nothing changed. any further suggestion ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try it please.

Comment: I've tried this also. still the same result and no other clues to try.

Comment: Have you tried to restart?

Comment: VMware-player 2.5.5